# red5 server installation error

Tags: red5, centos6.5

I have installed red5 server following this guide: http://tecadmin.net/installing-red5-media-server-on-centos-6/

I am able to access red5-server on port 5080.

But when I try to access "http://:5080/installer/" I get following error:

```
Trying to connect to war location
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Failed
```

I have opened following network port 5080, 1935, 8081, 9998 and 9999.
I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of the googlecode shutdown; the fix is described here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/issues/180

Change your *webapps/installer/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties* file. Change the **application.repository.url** parameter from:

```
application.repository.url=http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/
```

to

```
application.repository.url=http://red5.org/snapshots/
```

Comment: I changed the "application.repository.url"  parameter to "http://red5.org/snapshots/". But there is no effect even after this, it throws the same error as earlier.

Comment: Turn on / click the debug option on the installer and see if that helps

Comment: I ran ./red5-debug.sh after shutting down the server with ./red5-shutdown.sh. I was looking in the log files ./logs/red5.log but could not find any relevant message that I can use to troubleshoot. Could you please guide me further. Ports that  I have opened - 5080, 1935, 8081, 9998 and 9999 are correct ?

Comment: Your local ports dont matter beyond your initial connection in your browser to http://localhost:5080/installer the swf there connects to rtmp://localhost:1935 and then the server app "installer" connects to the application.repository.url shown above

Comment: I am not running server on localhost. I am running the server on an EC2 instance, and I am connecting from my local machine via browser. And these ports I have opened on the server - 5080, 1935, 8081, 9998 and 9999 to accept connection from anywhere. Where can I see the logs in the debug mode to inspect the issues ?

Comment: Open the red5/conf/logback.xml file and set the default to DEBUG and you'll see a lot more log entries.

Comment: Its saying trying to connect to war location, could this be related to file permission problem, or java problem.

Comment: You'd have to look at the installer flash/flex source to see where that's coming from idk

Comment: Where exactly should I set the default to DEBUG, in the file you mentioned.